# extract text from javascript

Tags: javascript, iphone, objective-c, ios

The data returned when i send a request with NSURLconnection contains script like this

```
<script>
var baseURL = "main.aspx?";
var lang = 1;
lg(0,8375,"AFC U-22 Championship Qualifirs","http://images.goalzz.com/i.aspx?i=competitions%2fafc_small_icon.gif");
mc(0,752017,1,"","11:45®<br><nobr>&nbsp;<font color=yellow>playing",1298,"","Malaysia","","",2163,"","Myanmar","","<font color=#427384>Week: 5<br>","",0);
mc(0,752021,2,"","12:00®<br><nobr>&nbsp;<font color=yellow>playing",7849,"","Laos","","",2158,"","Cambodia","","<font color=#427384>Week: 5<br>","",0);
mc(0,752022,3,"","12:00®<br><nobr>&nbsp;<font color=yellow>playing",479,"","Bahrain","","",1574,"","Iran","","<font color=#427384>Week: 5<br>","",0);
lg(6,8048,"Wimbledon - Men","http://images.goalzz.com/i.aspx?i=tennis%2ftennis_small.gif");
mc(6,754074,4,"","10:30®<br><nobr><font color=yellow>2nd Set",274,"","Brian Baker  - <font size=-1 color=black>United States</font>","","<font color=blue>1&nbsp;:&nbsp;1</font>",110,"","<font size=-1 color=orange>(27) </font>Philipp Kohlschreiber  - <font size=-1 color=black>Germany</font>","","<font color=red>Round 4<br>","",0);
mc(6,754076,5,"","10:30®<br><nobr><font color=yellow>2nd Set",342,"","<font size=-1 color=orange>(5) </font>Jo-Wilfried Tsonga  - <font size=-1 color=black>France</font>","","<font color=blue>0&nbsp;:&nbsp;1</font>",282,"","<font size=-1 color=orange>(10) </font>Mardy Fish  - <font size=-1 color=black>United States</font>","","<font color=red>Round 4<br>","",0);
mc(6,753844,6,"","10:30®<br><nobr><font color=yellow>3rd Set",5,"","<font size=-1 color=orange>(18) </font>Richard Gasquet  - <font size=-1 color=black>France</font>","","<font color=blue>1&nbsp;:&nbsp;2</font>",86,"","<font size=-1 color=orange>(31) </font>Florian Mayer  - <font size=-1 color=black>Germany</font>","","<font color=red>Round 4<br>","",0);
mc(6,754075,7,"","11:00®<br><nobr><font color=yellow>2nd Set",107,"","<font size=-1 color=orange>(7) </font>David Ferrer  - <font size=-1 color=black>Spain</font>","","<font color=blue>1&nbsp;:&nbsp;1</font>",669,"","<font size=-1 color=orange>(9) </font>Juan Martin Del Potro  - <font size=-1 color=black>Argentina</font>","","<font color=red>Round 4<br>","",0);
mc(6,754092,8,"","11:00®<br><nobr><font color=yellow>3rd Set",675,"","<font size=-1 color=orange>(16) </font>Marin Cilic  - <font size=-1 color=black>Croatia</font>","","<font color=blue>0&nbsp;:&nbsp;2</font>",16,"","<font size=-1 color=orange>(4) </font>Andy Murray  - <font size=-1 color=black>United Kingdom</font>","","<font color=red>Round 4<br>","",0);
</script>
```

i want to extract the (AFC U-22 Championship Qualifirs) text in lg node and (Malaysia,Myanmar) in mc node.is this possible ?

Comment: Its possible to parse it. But why don't you consider returning such strings in xml or json format which are far easier to parse.

Comment: thanks @Praveen as i said when i send the request the data returned like this .how i can return the script in json or xml.i am new in this stuff.

Comment: Where do you send this request? Why is the response a js string?

Comment: i send the request to this link (http://www.goalzz.com/main.aspx?region=-1&area=6)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do String Search in this.This [link](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Working_with_String_Objects_in_Objective-C) will help you to achieve this. You can follow these steps.

1. Search for "lg(" in your text data you have received from connection.
2. Then Search for second  appearance of comma "," and extract all character from next position till it does not get double quote " " ".
3. Then move your index and Search for "mc(" in the text.
4. Now search for 7th appearance of the comma "," and extract all character from next position till it does not get double quote """.

Now you can get both the strings.

Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

You will have to do some string manipulation and search

For example you could search for the string that comes between Championship (Championship Qualifirs",") and the first occurance of  ");

For Malaysia and Myanmar use a similar search approach, there are not built in functions that could parse this kind of string

If you have control over this request, consider using JSON or XML as remote data